# How can I summarize all the resource limits and requests in Kubernetes with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

I started using [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) and noticed that it gives you some warnings when the pods inside the nodes have limits higher than the actual capacity.
[image: A graphic visualization from Lens where you can see a warning telling that the specified limits are higher than the node capacity]

So I tried to get this information with *kubectl* but I'm new to *jsonpath* and I just managed to get the raw info using something like this:

```sh
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items..resources.limits}' -A
```

That produces something like this:

```json
{"cpu":"200m","memory":"1Gi"} {"cpu":"200m","memory":"1Gi"} {"cpu":"200m","memory":"512Mi"} {"cpu":"500m","memory":"250Mi"} {"memory":"170Mi"} {"memory":"170Mi"} {"cpu":"2","memory":"2Gi"} {"cpu":"2","memory":"2Gi"} {"cpu":"2","memory":"2Gi"} {"cpu":"1","memory":"1Gi"} {"cpu":"1","memory":"1Gi"} {"cpu":"2","memory":"2Gi"} {"cpu":"100m","memory":"128Mi"} {"cpu":"100m","memory":"128Mi"} {"cpu":"500m","memory":"600Mi"} {"cpu":"1","memory":"1Gi"} {"cpu":"100m","memory":"25Mi"} {"cpu":"100m","memory":"25Mi"}
```

So, my questions are, how can I sum all these values? Will these values be accurate or am I missing any other query? I've checked using LimitRange and the values I got seem to be correct, the results include the limits set by the LimitRange configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible with just `kubectl` commands. However, you can use the output of `kubectl` and write a basic shell script to compute the total values.

The following shell script will output total CPU limits(in `m` units) of all the pods in all namespaces.

```
res=$(kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*]..resources.limits.cpu}' -A)
let tot=0
for i in $res
do
   if [[ $i =~ "m" ]]; then
      i=$(echo $i | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
      tot=$(( tot + i ))
   else
      tot=$(( tot + i*1000 ))
   fi
done
echo $tot
```

You can extend the above to compute the CPU requests and the memory requests and limits values as well.

Comment: Just a heads up, the provided jsonpath also includes the resources of **initContainers** as well.  If you want to exclude them, change `.items[*]..resources` to `.items[*]..containers..resources`.

Comment: By extension you can also limit to a host by adding a field-selector: `--field-selector=spec.nodeName=<nodename>` in `res=$(...)`

Answer (score 23):

you can use a kubectl plugin to list/sort pods with cpu limits:

```
kubectl resource-capacity --sort cpu.limit --util --pods
```

https://github.com/robscott/kube-capacity

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace <your-namespace> --no-headers=true \
  -o custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name, CPU_REQUEST:.spec.containers[*].resources.requests.cpu, MEMORY_REQUEST:.spec.containers[*].resources.requests.memory' \
  | awk 'BEGIN {cpu=0; memory=0} {cpu+=$2; memory+=$3} END {print "Total CPU Requests: " cpu "\nTotal Memory Requests: " memory}'
```

Comment: I took the part before awk - it works perfectly. Awk command messed up the results because when requested cpu is in milli cores it doesnt calculate correctly total cpu

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do so with the use of the `kubectl` solely.

However, you could for example consider using:

1. [JSON `$sum()` function](https://docs.jsonata.org/aggregation-functions.html#sum):

> Returns the arithmetic sum of an array of numbers.

2. [Metrics-server, Grafana and Prometheus](https://itnext.io/k8s-monitor-pod-cpu-and-memory-usage-with-prometheus-28eec6d84729):

> We’ll walk through steps necessary to monitor how much resources (CPU
> or memory) a Kubernetes pod is using. Hence we’ll look at:
>
> - CPU requests / limits / actual usage / throttling
> - Memory requests / limits / actual usage / termination

or alternatively [monitor Kubernetes Node CPU and Memory Requests/Limits](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics):

> Node CPU requests/limits are a sum of the CPU requests/limits for all
> pods running on that node. Similarly, node memory requests/limits are
> a sum of memory requests/limits of all pods

3. [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics#overview):

> kube-state-metrics is a simple service that listens to the Kubernetes
> API server and generates metrics about the state of the objects. (See
> examples in the Metrics section below.) It is not focused on the
> health of the individual Kubernetes components, but rather on the
> health of the various objects inside, such as deployments, nodes and
> pods.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the common tool `jq` to process the `json` output that `kubectl` provides. At least in simple cases where each value for `cpu.request` has the same unit.

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath-as-json='{.items..containers..resources.requests}' -A | jq "([.[].cpu[0:-1] | tonumber] | add) / 1000 / 4"
```

Assuming that each `cpu.request` is in the unit millicore, this command will output the amount of core the current workloads needs in a perfect packing of the pods.

For cases where the units do not match this is not so easy and requires more effort and at that point it is probably worth it to write a bash/pwsh/python script to do the processing.